# I need to change link in HTML when an option on select, selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option with 4 languages, and I want when I choose a language to link it to it's HTML.

```
<select>
    <option value="Hebrew">עברית</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Arabic ">العربية</option>
    <option value="Russian">русский</option>
</select>
```

And then change

```
<div class="selected selected-tab-2-color  mobile">
    <a href="tab2.html">
        <span>עסקים ומוסדות</span>
    </a>
    <div class="show-triangle triangle-color-2"></div>
</div>
```

To `<a href="left-to-right/tab2.html">`

Comment: you need to change link in href in `<a>` tag?

Comment: what javascript have you written to solve the problem?

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question. You want to add "left-to-right" to hebrew and arab?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onchange` event in the select box.

Try this code:

```
<SELECT onchange="window.location.href=this.options [this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="Hebrew.html">עברית</option>
<option value="English.html">English</option>
<option value="Arabic.html">العربية</option>
<option value="Russian.html">русский</option>
</SELECT>
```

For example, consider a website: *http://www.example.com/*.

If the user changes the select box to **English**, then the browser will be redirected to *http://www.example.com/English.html*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var langVal = $(this).val();
    $('.mobile a span').text(langVal);
});
```

Above solution will change the span text according to your select option

Answer (score 0):

You can use onChange for your solution.

```html
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.de">Google</option>
    <option value="www.yahoo.com">Yahooo</option>
 <option value="left-to-right/tab2.html">עברית</option>
 <option value="left-to-right/tab2.html">English</option>
 <option value="left-to-right/tab2.html ">العربية</option>
    <option value="left-to-right/tab2.htmlian">русский</option>
</select>
```